# ِIs it correct reasoning?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am reading my friend explanation for a question , in proof of one theorem he writes that A1,A2,..⊆X
then closure of ∪ A<sub>n</sub>
<sub><sub>n⩾1</sub></sub> = ∪ closure of A<sub>n</sub>
<sub><sub>n⩾1</sub></sub>.
I thing that its not correct but I cant find any counterexample ? Am I right ?does anybody can give me a counter example ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: Take $X=\Bbb R$, and $A_n=[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$. Then $$\overline{\bigcup_{n\geq1} A_n}=\overline{[0,1)}=[0,1]$$ but $$\bigcup_{n\geq1} \overline{A_n}=\bigcup_{n\geq1} {A_n}=[0,1)$$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60038/provide-an-example-where-overline-cupa-a-supsetneq-cup-overlinea-a?rq=1)